# How to remove newline character and white spaces after them and replacing them with just whitespace character in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

How can I write a regex pattern with Perl that will work like that:

`**If there is a new line**, after it, it will remove that new line character and all the whitespace characters after until it sees any character except for a white space character and will put just one whitespace character instead of them?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[substitution operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $s = "foo\n    bar goo\nber";
$s =~ s/\n\s*/ /g;
print "$s\n";

__END__

foo bar goo ber
```

Comment: \s* means it will match even if there is no whitespace after the newline. If you only want to match newline with whitespace, use \s+

Comment: No, you surely want `perl -0777 -pe 's/\R\h+/ /g'`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand your question well. Try: `s{ \n\s+ }{ }gx`